# how to store data locally

Tags: ios, datastore

So i have no idea how to manipulate data effectively.  Currently I am querying all my data (messages) from my backend and manipulating it within the view controller file and passing it among view controllers via segues.  I realize this is probably ridiculous for a messaging app.

I am thinking of making a separate file called data in order to manipulate the data effectively.  The data consists of the message body, object id, sender name, sender id, and time stamp.  I was also planning on making custom classes to handle this data.

Would it be best to take this route and how do I effectively manipulate data from other view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SQLite to save all data.You can create a new table and query all data.It's easy to learn and use.Good luck.

Comment: I already have a table on my backend parse.com. To be clear, you are saying I should use the sqlite bundle in xcode to make another table (stored locally) from the data i queried from my backend, and then use sqlite again to manipulate that data?